Issue with Creating Custom Reports in GA4 Integrated with Firebase
Iam a beginner in GA4.
The company has Google Analytics 4 integrated with Firebase. It is very simplified, and I can't create any custom reports. It was mentioned that it is necessary to create a "standard" Google Analytics 4 account and connect the database to Firebase.
In the Firebase project, I have editor permission in Firebase, and I can't do anything in GA4.
I need some documentation to resolve this issue, or a video.
I tried changing permissions to get access to custom reports, but the GA4 in Firebase is different from the standard GA4.
